# Appending to a Series dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append to a `Series` Object within a loop as seen in the code below, but find that the appending is not taking place at all.  `bond.to_cash_flows().amounts` results in a Series like the one shown below and I am just trying to append to this Series.

For example, one of the Series looks like:

```
     1983-05-15      1
     1983-11-15      1
     1984-05-15      1
     1984-11-15     101
```

`list_of_data` and `indices_of_data` are working as required. And as `print(list_of_data) = [0 0]` and `print(indices_of_data) = [datetime.date(2018, 5, 15), datetime.date(2018, 11, 15)]` I need the above Series to look like:

```
     1983-05-15      1
     1983-11-15      1
     1984-05-15      1
     1984-11-15     101
     2018-5-15       0
     2018-11-15      0
```

However, `print('SERIES', bond.to_cash_flows().amounts)` results in the same series as before and I don't know why this is.

```
for bond in bonds:
    list_of_data = [0] * (length_of_series_max_maturity - len(bond.to_cash_flows().amounts))
    print(list_of_data)
    indices_of_data = list(set(indices_of_series_max_maturity)^set(bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index))
    print(indices_of_data) 
    print(bond.to_cash_flows().amounts)
    series = pandas.Series(list_of_data, indices_of_data)
    bond.to_cash_flows().amounts = bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.append(series)
    print('SERIES', bond.to_cash_flows().amounts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that

```
bond.to_cash_flows()
```

is a method call and the output (and it's attributes) can't change 
by assignment in the way you've done. That is, the line

```
bond.to_cash_flows().amounts = bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.append(series)
```

has no effect. You could do something like

```
amounts = bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.append(Series)
print('SERIES', amounts)
```

Not sure this will solve the problem as I don't know the context but it will print what you want in the example

Comment: Thanks. I see. So, how could I replace this line?